# How to replace string in sentence by index position

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas

How can I move a matching substring in a given sentence to the start of the sentence?

`col1` is always lowercase.

I have:

```
col1      col2                          output
mmm2      Hello I want Mmm2 replace it  Mmm2 Hello I want replace it
mmm5      I want MMM5 replace it        MMM5 I want replace it
mmm1      I mmm1 want replace it        mmm1 I want replace it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to use `list.insert` and `list.pop` to move your word to the start. This can be combined with `pd.DataFrame.apply`.

Data from @Rakesh.

```
import pandas as pd

def transporter(row):
    split = row['col2'].split()
    idx = next((i for i, j in enumerate(split) if j.lower() == row['col1']), None)
    if not idx:
        return row['col2']
    else:
        split.insert(0, split.pop(idx))
        return ' '.join(split)

df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["mmm2", "mmm5"],
                   "col2": ["Hello I want Mmm2 replace it", "I want MMM5 replace it"]})

df['col2'] = df.apply(transporter, axis=1)

print(df)

   col1                          col2
0  mmm2  Mmm2 Hello I want replace it
1  mmm5        MMM5 I want replace it
```

Answer (score 0):

One method:

```
start_index = string.lower().index(target)
new_string = target+string[0:start_index]+string[start_index+len(target):]
```

This will throw an error if `target` is not in `string`, and will only move the first instance if there are multiple.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the right approach. I am using regex to get your required output.

**Demo:**

```
import pandas as pd
import re
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1": ["mmm2", "mmm5"], "col2": ["Hello I want Mmm2 replace it", "I want MMM5 replace it"]})

df["output"] = df.apply(lambda row: re.sub(row["col1"], "", row["col2"], flags=re.IGNORECASE), axis=1)
df["output"] = df.apply(lambda row: "{0} {1}".format(re.search(row["col1"], row["col2"], flags=re.IGNORECASE).group(0), row["output"]), axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
   col1                          col2                         output
0  mmm2  Hello I want Mmm2 replace it  Mmm2 Hello I want  replace it
1  mmm5        I want MMM5 replace it        MMM5 I want  replace it
```